# Are location-sensitive reminders bad for battery life and/or data usage?

Tags: iphone, ios, battery, reminders, gps

If I understand iOS's location-aware reminders correctly, they work by constantly checking your location until they see that you're in the specified range.

Wouldn't this be really detrimental to the iPhone, both to its battery life, for always needing to find your location, and to cell data usage, for always needing to get your GPS location and compare it to Maps?

Comment: This should have the answer for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253113/ios-region-monitoring-and-battery-usage     Also, iOS doesn't necessarily utilize GPS/Location Services constantly to determine location - it's set by predefined regions. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html

Comment: Thank you! I didn't see that Stack Overflow question because I'd assumed any questions similar to mine would be on Ask Different.